# What are some of the main considerations when tracking all product end users as contacts in Salesforce?

Tags: marketo

Up until now, my org has used Contacts and Leads to track people that are part of the sales and implementations processes for our product, as well as people who are in our marketing database (Marketo).

Now, Product Marketing wants to start sending email blasts to our entire user base, so we are looking at having ALL end-users of our B2B product (anyone with a login) as contacts in Salesforce, since Marketo can only send email blasts to people who are in the database. Right now we're looking at inserting about 50k new contacts (about a 20% increase to our Contact storage).

What are some of the main considerations and tradeoffs to this structural shift? I am trying to impress upon Product Marketing that this is a strategic decision that should not happen on a whim, but I'm having trouble consolidating the argument to its core points.

One thing I know is that this database of end users will have to be maintained and kept up do date, either by an integration with our product backend or with periodic data loads. So there's maintenance overhead there. It may also affect performance, since the number of contacts per account will be much higher. Could this increase our risk of Lookup Skew?

I feel like I'm missing some important piece of the larger picture.

Comment: If these aren't primary account contacts, but instead marketing contacts, you'll want to create a different record type for them. That's the first thing I'd be looking at doing to help separate the two different types of contacts and keep your related contact pages cleaner so that only the record type you want displayed will show. The rest is probably much too specific to your org to answer here without more details.